# How to Refresh Miktek without the Miktex Console

Tags: miktex, directory, leadsheets

I have been trying to add the `leadsheets` package to my Miktex files by going to https://miktex.org/packages/leadsheets, downloading the file, unzipping the contents, and copying them to the LateX subdivsion of my Miktex folder. Alas, when trying to run a simple document that invokes the `leadsheets` package, it didn't work---but discovered by listening to an online video that I need (at last) to `refresh Miktek' to get the program to run.

The problem is---I do not have the Miktex console on my computer, nor, for some reason, am I able to download it.

QUESTION: Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may ``refresh Miktek'' in order that it may recognize the unzipped `LEADSHEETS` files that I have added to the directory?

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way would be to install MiKTeX: https://miktex.org/download . Once you did and configured it, just use any package in your document. If it's missing, MiKTeX will ask for permission to download it from a repository you can specify. It may take a minute, and it may find it has to download even more, but it works fine. // Additionally you'll get the console and can install packages directly.

Comment: you shouldn't put files in the main miktex folder. Create a folder "yourfolder" somewhere else. put your file into yourfolder/tex/latex and then add yourfolder as a new root in the console, tab settings. If you add more files you can "refresh" with the entry in the tasks menu.